# Вытянуть значение из Json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: req_ajx_host + "ajx/sharecount/",
    data: "&projid=<?=$proj['id'];?>",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#sharecount").html(data);
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Выводит строку:

> [{"sco":"12"}]

Как из строки сделать массив и вывести значение 12?

Comment: `data[0]['sco']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: req_ajx_host + "ajx/sharecount/",
    data: "&projid=<?=$proj['id'];?>",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#sharecount").html(data[0].sco);
        alert(data[0].sco)
    }
});
```

Вот так должно, по идее, заработать.

Comment: пишет undefined

Comment: да, добавил dataType и сделал data[0].sco - возвратило 0.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Более компактный вариант:

```
$.post(req_ajx_host+'ajx/sharecount/', {projid: <?=$proj['id'];?>}, function(data) {
 $("#sharecount").html(data[0].sco);
}, 'json');
```